# Case in-sensitve search with case sensitive sections

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In Core Data on iOS, I want to do a `@SectionedFetchRequest` with a predicate that does an case in-sensitive search on a field named "title" as the `sectionIdentifier`. I want the results to be sectioned on the title in a case sensitive manner.

So if I do a fetch looking for the title "A", I'll get back objects whose titles are "A" and "a" objects. The results would be two sections.

Is there some way to achieve this in Core Data just by using NSPredicates and the xcdatamodeld configuration? Right now it seems like if I have a predicate where it is case in-sensitive, then the sections are case in-sensitive.